# How to avoid comment color in xml when we have /*

Tags: support, comments, syntax-highlighting, xml

In case that we have /* in the XML code, it compiles as a comment. While, it doesn't mean comment in XML. How can we avoid it.
This is an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728993/how-to-exclude-poperties-file-from-jar-file#tab-top).

I have tried

> `<!-- language: lang-xml-->`

but it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why in this question the highlighting is ok, but in the example that I sent it is highlighted as comment

Comment: To answer you question, the highlighting in this question was ok because it was resolving the type (xml) by it self. Where as in the quesiton it was resolving the type to java since the question is tagged as java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this!

Your problem is that you wrote `<!--language: lang-xml-->` instead of `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` (See the missing space between `lang-xml` and `-->`!)

*Without the typo:*

```xml
<project>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
<project>
```

*With the typo:*

```java
<project>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
<project>
```

Comment: I tried it on your post without submitting the edits and it works.

Comment: StackEdit is silly in this regard then, spaces are not required after or before double-dashes (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)

Comment: @0A0D Maybe he is silly, but still he doesn't *have* to be fully html standard compliant though.

Comment: Well if you are going to use HTML I would expect you to comply.

Comment: @0A0D actually is not directly using html since it transforms the "markup" used to html (in this case it is a pre tag). So it could be considered as a special form of markup which is a subset of the html standard.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's too strict and silly to have as a requirement when the parser simply has to look for the end tag.